# Simplest way to change port of a Blazor app so two versions can run side by side

Tags: .net, blazor

I have two versions of Blazor project, the newer one with some problems. I'd like to trace them at the same time in the same PC, but can't do it because they both use the same root path and port.

What would be the simplest way to change the port of one of the projects so they can run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The ports for each site are set in *launchSettings.json* in the *Properties* folder.

[image]

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64180",
        "sslPort": 44398
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5145",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "https": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7016;http://localhost:5145",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The various startup options can be selected in the top toolbar.

[image]

Comment: 1) A while back, because of something I read somewhere, I placed several copies of launchsettings.json in all the Properties folders of all the projects in my solution. (ugh!)

2) So a first question: should I delete the incorrectly placed launchsettings.json files? And which are those? I suspect the good one is in the Blazor project.

3) Where does the server project look for the ip:port it should be listening to, or does it get that information from the same place that the client?

Comment: You only need launchsettings.json files in what I call deployment projects.  I've changed the image in the answer to show one of my projects.  The only project with a *launchsettings.json* is *Blazor.Server.Web*

Comment: You select the startup Profile in the toolbar as shown in the second image in the answer.  And you can change the IP address in the the profile by changing the applicationUrl.

Comment: Got it working. I am using Visual Studio, so it looks slightly different. Thnaks